# How to Access SQL Database in OpenModelica ? How can I establish connection with SQL database in Open Modelica Connector

Tags: python, sql, modelica, dymola, openmodelica

I'm pretty new to modelica , I'm trying to setup and simulate a headlamp module with OpenModelica Connector. Trying to setup it as dynamic module. so It requires some datas for calculation, those were stored in SQL and Excel database. I tried to import datas from Excel using ExternData. But its not handy, Is there a way to import Data's from SQL using some queries or is there any other ways to import datas from Excel ? Open Modelica connector supports python Interface.Is there a way to establish connection using Python? Thanks.

Sample code which gives access to Excel file in Modelica:

```
function computeColSum
  extends Modelica.Icons.Function;
  input ExternData.XLSXFile dataSource "Excel XLSX file record";
  input String col = "A" "Column";
  input String sheetName = "" "Sheet name";
  input Integer startRow = 2 "Start row";
  input Integer endRow = ExternData.Functions.XLSX.getArrayRows2D(sheetName = sheetName, xlsx = dataSource.xlsx) "End row";
  output Real colSum "Column sum";
end computeColSum;
```

Comment: Access of Access SQL DB is supported by SimulationX, but no queries, just single values if I am not wrong. I'd even claim it is not more comfortable than accessing Excel sheets through ExternData. Maybe you can be more specific what you actually want to access in the Excel file (row, column, range, single cell etc.) and what you want to achieve (set as parameter modifier, do calculations etc.).

Comment: I want to access around 1:20 columns and each contains upto 100 rows , to make calculations. is it possible?  What about HDF5 , will it be a replacement for SQL? @tbeu

Comment: 1) Yes, that is possible. 2) HDF5 can also be accessed by ExternData 3) HDF5 is just another data source variant.

Comment: Thanks for the response. can you share some script, with which we can access the 1:20 columns and 100 rows. also some supporting script to access HDF5 data. thanks.